# Centos yum resync installed packages

Tags: centos, yum

I am in a strange situation. I have a web server machine with CentOS release 6.6 (Final) installed with nginx, mysql, ISPConfig and Webmin which is working smoothly. Recently I noticed when using phpMyAdmin that a message was popping up saying that there is a newer version of phpMyAdmin. Webmin did not report any updates available, so I run `"yum update"` receiving many errors like:

```
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
```

After trying some configuration and did a `"yum clean all"`, restarting the server, I am able to run yum again, but now yum database seems like it has been erased or something. When I run `"yum list installed"` I get absolutely nothing! When I run `"yum update"` I get `"No Packages marked for Update"`. All repos are enabled. All the packages are installed, but now yum db has nothing inside. For example when I run `"yum install phpMyAdmin"` I get:

```
Installing:
 phpMyAdmin                    noarch   4.3.7-1.el6.remi      remi  4.5 M
Installing for dependencies:
 MAKEDEV                       x86_64   3.24-6.el6            base  89 k
 apr                           x86_64   1.3.9-5.el6_2         base  123 k
 apr-util                      x86_64   1.3.9-3.el6_0.1       base  87 k
 apr-util-ldap                 x86_64   1.3.9-3.el6_0.1       base  15 k
 audit-libs                    x86_64   2.3.7-5.el6           base  71 k
 basesystem                    noarch   10.0-4.el6            base  4.7 k
 bash                          x86_64   4.1.2-29.el6          base  907 k
 binutils                      x86_64   2.20.51.0.2-5.42.el6  base  2.8 M
......
Transaction Summary
===========================
Install     158 Package(s)

Total download size: 98 M
Installed size: 346 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

which means everything yum has installed so far is now wiped out from the yum db but is still installed.

Is there a way to restore yum database or to make yum detect which packages the server has installed?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was a totally destroyed RPM database.
What I did is that I used all the original RPMs to just update the db without installing anything.

You can find the list of installed packages in the files `/root/install.log` or `/var/log/yum.log*` if you have yum log installed. If you don't have log files, then you can collect all the installed packages from yum database directory structure with this PHP script [yumdb_scan.php](http://zikro.gr/scripts/yumdb_scan.php.txt).

I wish I had all my RPMs cached, but I finally manage to find everything by searching on RPM search sites. I also created another script to download everything I have installed and was on the base OS [repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/). Then I collected all the RPM packages, did a verification that I had all of them and create another script that it uses `rpm -Uvh --nodeps --justdb {$pckg}` to update RPM db for every installed package without altering any system files.

All done well and now I can finally use yum to install new packages and update old ones using repos.

So my steps were:

1. Search system for installed RPMs and create a file listing them all.
2. Collect all the RPMs you have installed on system with matching
   versions for all.
3. Use `rpm -Uvh --nodeps --justdb <package-path>` to
   put RPM record to RPM database without installing any files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation before. What I did:

1. Make a list of all files on the filesystem.
2. Download the SQLite DBs of the yum repos from which I had files.
3. Create a script that queries the SQLite DBs for which package provides each file and reinstall the packages.

Not really the fastest solution. If it was not a critical system, I would have rebuilt it.

Comment: I could not find the SQLite DBs, but it was not the yum db that was corrupted, but the whole RPM database. You gave me an idea on how I could collect and rebuild the RPM database, thank you. Please see my answer. Can't up vote your answer, not enough rep.